# Is there any voltage regulation on this board from an Apple Trackpad teardown?

Tags: voltage-regulator, apple

Board: [image: Apple Magic Trackpad logic board]

[Teardown](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Magic+Trackpad+Teardown/3395), with brief descriptions of the major chips below:

- Red: Broadcom BCM2042 for Bluetooth connectivity
- Orange: Broadcom BCM5974 touch screen controller chip
- Yellow: SST 25WF020 provides 2 Mbit of serial flash memory
- Blue: TI CD3238 RS232 line driver/receiver.

Context: I have an Apple Magic Trackpad, the old version. It is modified for improved ergonomics. It also eats batteries (like 2 AAs per week). I want to just plug it in instead of dealing with batteries.

I have connected the trackpad to an AA-shaped power adapter, which is directly connected to a USB plug. Obviously the trackpad expects 3v, and USB supplies 5v. Do I need to put a voltage regulator or other step-down solution in between the trackpad and the plug? Or is the board already doing something that addresses this? I started looking up some of the chips, but have not yet found a definitive answer, and I hoped someone here would be able to tell at a glance.

For example, according to [this](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/175090/BOARDCOM/BCM2042.html), "A key component enabling the BCM2042 to reach extremely low system cost is the inclusion of a high-performance boost regulator. This enables direct connect with mouse electronics requiring 3-volt operation without
adding expensive external components".

Yes, there may be something wrong with this device, it didn't always eat batteries like this. Yes, I could buy a new one, designed to be charged via USB. This would be more expensive, and slower (due to needing to re-design the ergonomic mod for a new form factor). Even if I need to adjust the voltage, this is still the fastest, most convenient solution for me.

Comment: Please post the schematic or link every single chip used on the circuit board to their respective data sheets.

Comment: @Andyaka pardon me, but is that request serious or sarcastic? Part of my reason for posting is that I think it is at least possible that someone can quickly answer, or point me in the right direction, *without* needing to explicitly research each chip. If that turns out not to be true, no problem. But I don't think it's an unreasonable question.

Comment: It's a serious request; as a designer, that's the route I'd take if I were interested in locating a voltage regulator on the circuit board. I don't know how you could have thought anything else given that this site is about electronic and electrical design. If you are hoping to find somebody who has intimate knowledge of the circuit board already then you are cutting down on the number of folk who can answer significantly. But, then again, there are probably better sites than this to ask this question if you are hoping to find someone with intimate knowledge.

Comment: Not so much intimate knowledge of the specific board, but rather the chips, product lines, and manufacturers that are likely shared across many products. Broadcom isn't some hole-in-the-wall bluetooth chipset shop. If I get a helpful answer, great; if I don't, I understand.

Comment: I would expect the AA power adapter to have its own internal voltage regulation.  A AA adapter that outputs 5V wouldn't seem to have any normal application.

Comment: @vir I agree that would be a more sensible product design for the adapter, but I guess the cheap version won, it seems to be more common. I assume the expectation is that it will be used with devices with built-in regulators, so it works automatically for any device with 1-3 AAs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes; circled in red below.

[image: regulators circled]

At least three, including one most likely onboard the Broadcom chip, as you note.

Regulators are fairly easy to spot as they are almost always paired with inductors -- these are most likely switching regulators.  What are not so easy to spot are LDOs (which have lower efficiency, but no inductor is required), charge pumps (switching but using capacitors only, usually to make rough voltages; or in combination with an LDO externally, internally, or in effect, for regulated outputs at modest efficiency), or integrated modules (very high frequency regulators are available these days which integrate the inductor in-package, or indeed even on-chip).

Whether this means anything with respect to input or output voltage or current ratings is another matter entirely.

As Andy aka commented, this may not be very useful without complete schematics.  I don't know about this device in particular, but Apple in general is notorious for using proprietary variations of commercially available chips.  You may not be able to identify all components on the board, even if you're willing to trace the circuit and reconstruct the schematic, at least in relevant part (such as around the power-input section so you can figure out the ratings).  Or if you can, datasheets may not be available.  It is a complex design, almost certainly multilayer, and I don't know how many components are on the backside.  While it can be reverse-engineered, it will take very many more hours than the equivalent value of buying a new one.

Comment: Thanks for the info. That's all I need to decide not to risk plugging it in to 5v, I'm not interested in turning this into a reverse engineering project. For posterity, the teardown shows nothing on the back except for traces and test points.